# discord.js bot returns as undefined when trying to get SQLite value

Tags: discord.js, better-sqlite3

Whenever I run the command, I get `you have undefined` instead of the number inputted in the SQLite database.

```
if (command === "bal") {

        if (message.author.bot) return;

        const data = sql.prepare(`SELECT ${args} FROM ${'acc' + message.guild.id + message.member.id}`).get();

        message.channel.send(`You have ${data.args}`)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `.catch()` block to handle err and await before select request. 
Like this:

```js
      if (command === "bal") {

            if (message.author.bot) return;

            const data =  await sql.prepare(`SELECT ${args} FROM ${'acc' + message.guild.id + message.member.id}`).get().catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
            });


            message.channel.send(`You have ${data.args}`)
        }
```

> Looks like you try select from table with **name** `${'acc' +
>   message.guild.id + message.member.id}` ,and table doesn\'t exist.

The rigth syntax is like:

SELECT **COLUMNS NAMES** FROM **TABLE NAME HERE** WHERE **FIELD = somethink**

Comment: Now I am getting ``(node:50347) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Too few parameter values were provided``. Forgot to mention that before that, there is a const that is ``const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);``

Comment: please write in more detail what actions you want to do. Choose what data? from which table? what value? at the moment, it’s hard to provide you any help without understanding these introductory notes. Also tell me what specific values ​​you have in `args`

Comment: Alright so basically, this is part of an economy system. What I want to do is for the user to create an account using 'acc + guild ID + member ID.', basically, what happens is that when they run the command to create the account, it results in a table called acc1252325235475923 or something. 

Here I am trying to catch the data from the column that was created previously with ``ta create``, while ``args`` is the name inputted by the user. For example, lets say someone created a database called Jeff, ``ta bal Jeff`` needs to retrieve whats written in said column.

Comment: (continuing from before) . The column comes from the table ``acc + guild id + member id``, having the columns that were created by the user themselves. The bot is supposed to grab the data whats in the column ``Jeff`` from the table ``acc(guildid)(memberid)``

Comment: Correction, the table was created previously with ``ta create``, and the column created via another command ``ta addname (args)``

Comment: You create table for every user?

Comment: Well, every user that runs the command ``ta create``, creates a new table with ``acc`` in the beginning, ``guild id`` and ``member id`` together, making something like ``acc2758923975629732879768``

Comment: Ohh, why you do thats ? Are sure its create table, not insert row to database?

Comment: ``CREATE TABLE`` is what is ran when the command ``ta create`` is executed. After that, it is unnecessary to create a new table. ``ta addname (name)`` is supposed to add a new column inside of the table ``acc(insert long strand of numbers here)``. And ``ta bal`` is meant to get the data from the column created with that custom name

Comment: So try this way.
`const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM TALBENAME WHERE YOURCOLUMNSSTATMENT = ?')` WHERE `TALBENAME` its database table name and `YOURCOLUMNSSTATMENT` its column name for acc(guildid)(memberid). And then get it with `let result = stmt.run(\`acc${message.guild.id}${message.member.id}\`);`

Comment: I've tried adding in the following: ``const stmt = sql.prepare(`SELECT * FROM ${'acc' + message.guild.id + message.member.id} WHERE ${args} = ?`);
    let res = stmt.run(`acc${message.guild.id}${message.member.id}`);``. However, I am getting an error ``(node:51220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: This statement returns data. Use get(), all(), or iterate() instead`` on ``let res = stmt.run(`acc${message.guild.id}${message.member.id}`);``. I replaced ``stmt.run`` with ``stmt.get`` and got ``You have undefined``

Comment: `TABLE NAME` its not `\`acc${message.guild.id}${message.member.id}\``, the `\`acc${message.guild.id}${message.member.id}`\` its key of selected row. 
How you constant `prepare` in this function ?